# Laravel Slack notifications using relationships

Tags: php, laravel

There seems to be no documentation on this (correct me if I'm wrong), but basically, I want to access the relationships set in my models.
I noticed that you can link data using $this->(variable put into the notification).
If anyone has some experience using the notifications in Laravel 5.3, or found some documentation or anything, please let me know!

Comment: did you watch @Jeffrey series ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

watch this [LINK 1](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-3/episodes/9) [Link 2](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-3/episodes/10) this jeffrey's video tutorial so you will get good understand.

i hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

I just got it working, by including a new variable in  the __construct function, which is standard in the notification class. After this, I could reference to the related data.